# How do I get purchase(s) from iOS in app purchases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I want to get purchase or purchases made by the user even if purchased from other devices.

Comment: i want it on Objective-c, thanks for the correction & -1 @rmaddy

Comment: Don't make assumptions about who votes. Regardless, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and learn how to ask a question here. Your question is far too vague and broad for this site.

Comment: @rmaddy i worth it x) im bad in english

Comment: it is very difficult to get objective c tutorial but I suggest you to check these 3 websites : 1) https://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/ 2) https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial and 3) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm (for Objective -C).

Answer (score 0):

When an in-app purchase is purchased on one device, it is marked as a purchase by the user. So, a non-consumable purchase is available on all devices owned by the user after a single purchase.

If you create a consumable purchase and handle it using the login of your app, you should be able to do this. Of course, Apple's review process will check whether this is fair by the user.

Comment: See https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial and use consumable purchases.